# Wpf Application cross (X) Button not working on single Click

Tags: c#, wpf, buttonclick

I have a WPF application and what problem I am facing is my Application doesnt get closed on single cross(X) button click.
May be I know the reason-

Initially what happening is I am setting Focus to a MenuItem when window is loaded,so when I click on the Cross(X) button first the focus from MenuItem is removed and then on second click the application Cross(x) button works.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem1.Focus();               
}
```

But when I dont set the Focus on the MenuItem,the Cross button works on single click.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // MenuItem1.Focus();                 
}
```

I want to set the focus on the MenuItem and want the Red Cross(X) button to execute on singleClick..

Is their any way that this scenario can be achieved..???

Comment: Something *has* to have the focus, your close button should work regardless of focus. Can you verify, that this does not happen if you don't set the focus? If it does not, can you post a small, compilable example?

Comment: see the edited version if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur that this behaviour is happening... a `MenuItem` is not the same as a `Button` having focus. @Samuel, `FocusManager.IsFocusScope` has no effect here. When the `Menu` is focused, it even stops the window from being moved or re-sized, let alone having any of its `Button`s clicked.

I tried implementing other events such as `MouseLeave` and `LostFocus` (on the window) all without the ability to change this focused `MenuItem`.

I don't know why Farzi wants it to be automatically focused, but I would suggest that this is a bad idea. Maybe what Farzi wants can be achieved in a different way? Maybe temporarily colouring the `MenuItem.Background` instead?

Comment: Ya I have set the background instead of setting the Focus and it is working..But I just wana no why cross button doesnt get execute on single click it should work regardless of the focus set on other control as @nvoigt said

Comment: That is just the way that Microsoft decided to implement `Focus` in `Menu` controls. If you add a `Button` with a `Click` handler that calls `MenuItem1.Focus();`, you will see that this is the normal behaviour. After clicking this `Button`, you won't be able to move or close the window on the first click.

Comment: Ya..so I guess I just have an option to remove focus and set the background of the menuItem which will show as if it is focused..

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing issues with the logical scope provided by the FocusManager. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx

Here are related issues with focus scopes and an explanation: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f5de6ffc-fa03-4f08-87e9-77bbad752033/a-focusscope-nightmare-bug-commands-are-disabled
You can work around this by setting FocusManager.IsFocusScope to false on the menu, how ever this will created some usability issues as menus work better with an own logical scope.